# How can I create an Accessory app using Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

I've recently discovered that an "Accessory apps" section exists within the phone's settings, and I'd be interested in trying to create a Windows Phone version of the accessory's official app that's only available for Android devices.

My question is, what are the steps to develop such apps using Visual Studio? I've been looking for a template, but haven't found any so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of today, unless you are an OEM who is granted special privilege by Microsoft, you cannot create an accessory app. Although the classes in `Windows.Phone.Notification.Management` are visible in Visual Studio, attempting to use any of them will result in an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.